# How to move tableview to new tableview with button outside tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

So I want to to transfer my tableview from "ViewController" to my "SecondViewController" with button "Move to new tableview"(Check picture).
And inside my tableview I want to have all cells I have added there with pelaajat.append

simulator and storyboard image give below.

[image]

[image]

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var pelaajat = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    @IBAction func movetoNewTableview(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: Any) {
        lisaaPelaajanNimi()
    }

    func lisaaPelaajanNimi(){

        pelaajat.append(textField.text!)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: pelaajat.count - 1, section: 0)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        textField.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pelaajat.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = pelaajat[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete{
            pelaajat.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you want is to move the cells(data) to another tableview inside another UIViewController ?

Comment: yeh and on that other UIViewController inside tableview also

Comment: Pass the data and show in the second view Controller in tableView...why move cells ??...when you can pass data......Give some more detail on what are you trying to achieve with this So that i can help you

Comment: You do not move views, you pass data that can be represented by the UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `UIButton` action, before you perform push you should pass `var pelaajat` to the new UIViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondViewController = segue.destination
    secondViewController.pelaajat = self.pelaajat
}
```

**In SecondViewController**, implement your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` as you wish, but using your `pelaajat` data again.

By doing this you preserve the data in your first view controller and can manipulate it according to your second view controller needs using new delegate/datasource.

**However**, if you don't want to implement the same methods all over again, you should create a subclass of `UITableView` and implement its delegate and datasource only once, then on your *Storyboard* you assign each `UITableView` class as your custom class.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to abstract your DataSource under separate class and pass it around those two UIViewControllers.

If you also want to share cell prototypes between multiple UITableView classes - easiest way to achieve that is to prepare those prototypes in separate .xib files (each UITableViewCell in a separate XIB).

Answer (score 0):

First solution: Send the data(pelaajat) to the other view controller with segue sender. And set the same value in second view controller.

Second solution: If you want to use the same table view in more than one view controller, you should create a base view controller and take the data from base view controller. If you want to update your all table view, there is one thing you have to do that is update your base view controller.